# Does addressindex works in satoshi Bitcoin-Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I'm wondering if addressindex in bitcoin config working in satoshi Bitcoin-core app, or just in BitPay bitcoin app.

> **addressindex**
>
> Records all changes to an address for retrieving txids,
> balances and unspent outputs for addresses. Changes are stored and
> sorted in block order. Both p2sh and p2pkh address types are
> supported. The index records two sets of key/value pairs. The first
> records all activity and is useful for viewing transaction history and
> all changes. The second is specifically for retrieving unspent outputs
> by address, and is smaller as values are removed once they are spent.

Comment: I have some extended software that could provide this. you need this information once or by request?

Comment: what do you mean? once or by request?

Comment: i can calculate it once for you, but my software is not under the public license for to share it. i mean for such real-time information need some motivations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [bitcoin core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) doesn't have such feature.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at the source code for a while and didn't find anything about it. there was just a suggestion from BitPay to add this feature.